# Add another div below after 5 secs in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am newbie to Jquery. I have two divs text and image related. First Text should display after 6 seconds image also should display below to this text in another div.....

```
 <div id="text">Loading Please wait</div>
 <div id="outer"><img src="http://existdissolve.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/microsoft-logo-     64x64.png" alt="" /></div>
```

I am new bie dont have much knowledge in Jquery..Please provide code to solve this Jquery

Thx.

Comment: Please try something yourself first. Go to http://api.jquery.com and read the documentation / try out a few examples.

Comment: Instead of asking for code, you might want to **[learn jquery in 30 days](https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/)**

Comment: your question body is different to your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo - http://jsbin.com/AxiMohI/2/edit

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#text,#outer').hide();
setTimeout(function(){$('#text').show();},6000); //show text on 6 sec
setTimeout(function(){$('#outer').show();},11000);// shows img 5 sec after text
});
```

Comment: What is that going to do?

Comment: you should really  test your answers, this wont work.

Comment: @Blowsie : thanks i missied something on hurry

Comment: @Amith this still wont work :P

Comment: Amit thanks for your reply i have tested in IE text displays and within fraction of second image also display below....to increase time of image loading I tried increasing 6000 to 60000 but no use....I need minimum of 5 sec of delay loading image...any inputs

Comment: @Rajesh : see updated code http://jsbin.com/AxiMohI/2/edit

Comment: Thx Amit for your response it worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [setTimeout function](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Here is an example :

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="text">Loading Please wait</div> <div id="outer"><img src="http://existdissolve.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/microsoft-logo-64x64.png" alt="" /></div>');
},6000);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this would result in may divs with the same id.

Comment: W3schools is a terrible resource. Use MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout